# Spring @GetMapping is being ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping, get-mapping

I have the following controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/{brand}")
public class CarController {

  private final CarService carService;

  @Autowird
  public CarController(CarService carService) {
    this.carService = carService;
  }

  @GetMapping
  public Resources<Car> getCars(@PathVariable("brand") String brand) {
    return new Resources<>(carService.getCars(brand));
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/{model}")
  public Car getModel(@PathVariable("brand") String brand, @PathVariable("model") String model) {
    return carService.getCar(brand, model);
  }
}
```

I would expect an http GET call to `http://localhost:8080/api/bmw` to return me the result of the `getCars` method. Instead, the call is delegated to the `getModel` method. This returns an error, because there is no `{model}` path variable.

How come my http calls are delegated to the incorrect `@GetMapping`?

Here you can see the version of `spring-boot-starter-web` that I pull in via `hateoas`:

> [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |  - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.9.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.26:compile
>   [INFO] |  |     - org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.26:compile
>   [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.25.2.RELEASE:compile
>   [INFO] |  - org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile

I've enabled the `mappings` endpoint of Spring Actuator and I can even see that the endpoint that is being ignored is available:

```
{
  "handler": "public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<com.example.Car> com.example.CarController.getCars(java.lang.String)",
  "predicate": "{GET /api/{brand}, produces [application/hal+json]}",
  "details": {
    "handlerMethod": {
      "className": "com.example.CarController",
      "name": "getCars",
      "descriptor": "(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/hateoas/Resources;"
    },
    "requestMappingConditions": {
      "consumes": [],
      "headers": [],
      "methods": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "params": [],
      "patterns": [
        "/api/{brand}"
      ],
      "produces": [
        {
          "mediaType": "application/hal+json",
          "negated": false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT I've added an [interceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) that enables me to see what the target `handlerMethod` will be.**

The `handlerMethod` is the correct one:

> public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources com.example.CarController.getCars(java.lang.String)

Yet I still get the following error:

> Internal server error: Missing URI template variable 'model' for method parameter of type String

I can't wrap my head around the fact that the `handlerMethod` does not expect the `model` parameter, but spring still throws an error because of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a `@RestControllerAdvice` was the culprit:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = {CarController.class})
public class InterceptModelPathParameterControllerAdvice {

  @Autowired
  CarService carService;

  @ModelAttribute
  public void validateModel(@PathVariable("model") String model) {
    if (!carService.isSupportedModel(model)) throw new RuntimeException("This model is not supprted by this application.");
  }
}
```

Because the `getCars` method did not have a `@PathVariable("model")`, the exception was being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, @RequestMapping("/api/{brand}") expects an input brand which is not found as you have used the annotation at class level. You can correct it the following way:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CarController {

  private final CarService carService;

  @Autowird
  public CarController(CarService carService) {
    this.carService = carService;
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/{brand}")
  public Resources<Car> getCars(@PathVariable("brand") String brand) {
    return new Resources<>(carService.getCars(brand));
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/{brand}/{model}")
  public Car getModel(@PathVariable("brand") String brand, @PathVariable("model") String model) {
    return carService.getCar(brand, model);
  }
}
```

So getCars() method will expect an input brand and getModel() will expect two inputs brand and model. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check your method mapping again:

As you said, you want to call gatCars method based on brand, you have to provide value in get mappings so function should be:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/{model}")
  public Resources<Car> getCars(@PathVariable("brand") String brand) {
    return new Resources<>(carService.getCars(brand));
  }
```

Request is going to getModel cause it matches the signature. Correct the getModel signature as below.

http://localhost:8080/api/bmw/x5

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/{model}/{brand}")
  public Car getModel(@PathVariable("brand") String brand, @PathVariable("model") String model) {
    return carService.getCar(brand, model);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a path variable can not be put into annotation `@RequestMapping` for the entire controller class. I suggest changing your `@RequestMapping("/api/{brand}")` to `@RequestMapping("/api")` and then change

```
  @GetMapping
  public Resources<Car> getCars(@PathVariable("brand") String brand) {
    return new Resources<>(carService.getCars(brand));
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/{model}")
  public Car getModel(@PathVariable("brand") String brand, @PathVariable("model") String model) {
    return carService.getCar(brand, model);
  }
```

to

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/{brand}")
  public Resources<Car> getCars(@PathVariable("brand") String brand) {
    return new Resources<>(carService.getCars(brand));
  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/{brand}/{model}")
  public Car getModel(@PathVariable("brand") String brand, @PathVariable("model") String model) {
    return carService.getCar(brand, model);
  }
```

Comment: [Adding a placeholder to the @RequestMapping is allowed](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path--). We have a lot of `@RestControllers` in our application that work fine like this. Only this one started behaving incorrectly.

Comment: @Titulum well, that's nice to know. I would still try my suggestion to see if somehow Spring mixes matching signatures and somehow gives you a false positive match. My proposal makes the difference between the signatures a bit more pronounced.

Comment: The link I posted was not talking about the same type of placeholders, but if you [check out the reference, they have an example there](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates). I have tried out your suggestion, but it leads to the same outcome. I have added some output of the `mappings` endpoint (Spring Actuator), to show that the endpoint really is there.

Comment: Well, my only idea at this point is to change `@GetMapping(value = "/{brand}/{model}")` to `@GetMapping(value = "/{brand}/model/{model}")` so the mapping matching will see those 2 URLs mutually exclusive. But other than that I don't have any ideas at the moment

Comment: That's a good idea, but I will probably have to customize the pattern matcher.